# Why is my date not being stored as NSDate?

Tags: ios, nsdate

My app takes a date string from a webservice and parses it into my core data db.  The webservice returns this format date:

```
1900-01-01T00:00:00
```

I take the string and use NSDateFormatter to convert it into an NSDate before sticking it into the db where the field is of type NSDate.  But when setting the value like this:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key forManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject {

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"createdAt"] || [key isEqualToString:@"updatedAt"]) {
        NSDate *date = [self dateUsingStringFromAPI:value];
        [managedObject setValue:date forKey:key];
        NSLog(@"the formatted date is %@", date);

    } else {
        [managedObject setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}
```

the NSDate *date = [self date...]; line displays invalid pointer if i mouse over NSDate *date.  And then, after the value is set, once it has gotten to the next line, managedObject setValue..., the date displays variable is not NSDate in both instances.  And the NSLog for formatted date returns:

the formatted date is:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

The values get stored in the db because Im looking at the db in MesaSQlite and it displays, for date is:

```
-3187296000
```

Why am I getting invalid pointer and variable not NSDate?

Here are the NSDateFormatter methods:

```
#pragma Date Formatting Methods
- (void)initializeDateFormatter {
    if (!self.dateFormatter) {
        self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
        [self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    }
}

- (NSDate *)dateUsingStringFromAPI:(NSString *)dateString {
    [self initializeDateFormatter];
    NSLog(@"dateString received from API == %@",dateString);
    NSLog(@"value sent to setValue:forKey == %@",[self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
    return [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Comment: could you provide the code for the method dateUsingStringFromAPI:? your problem is more likely there.

Comment: @EmanuelPeñaAguilar I pasted in the methods for the date.

Comment: Have you tried to just retrieve the NSManagedObject from the database and see if the NSDate stored is correct?